# Does there exist MATRIX games for more than two players

Tags: examples-counterexamples, game-theory

I am in a game theory course and I need to come up with an example of a Matrix game with more than two players

I have consulted https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_games_in_game_theory, but the ones that are more than two players cannot be posed as matrix games.

Note by matrix game I mean that there exists some matrices $A, B$ (for two players) that specifies the reward for the actions taken by player $1$ and player $2$. For more than two players, we need additional matrices.

Does there exists such a game?

Some thought experiment: for example, three players flip a coin simultaneously. If the coin lands on head, then player 1 wins. Tail, then player 2 wins. It doesn't seem that the third player has any role in it.

Comment: Can you define a "matrix game"?  I could imagine a definition that was equivalent to "2-player non-cooperative game with finite numbers of pure strategies and numerical payouts", which would make getting your example a bit tricky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution to this is to imagine a 3-D matrix, with payoffs represented as a triplet.

But if you want to write it down, you can have two separate matrices.

For example, if Player 1 can choose [up, down],
Player 2 can choose [left, right], Player 3 can choose [weak, strong], then we can first let Player 1 choose between [up, down].

Then, for each choice of up or down, we can make a 2x2 matrix for Players 2 and 3, and call them the "Up Matrix" and the "Down Matrix", both composing of choices that Players 2 and 3 can make, so the rows can consist of [left, right], and the columns consist of [weak, strong].

In practice, we do not make matrices for more than two players and rely on equations instead.

Comment: Yes, this is a common way to do it - usually called "left/right", "top/bottom", "up/down" or something analogous, nice.

Comment: Should they be "tensor games" or "hypermatrix games"? See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48045/why-are-matrices-ubiquitous-but-hypermatrices-rare

Comment: Great idea. Can this be generalized even further to four, or five players?

Comment: Of course! For example, for four players, the first player's choice can correspond to, borrowing kcrisman's terminology, one of the 3-d hypermatrices that I described. then we are back where we started with the 3 player case. In the end we'll have 2^(n-2) matrices for n player games.
edit: Assuming that every player has 2 choices.